# How to get set or array directly from query in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

As i can see only list method in query class in hibernate.How to get set or array directly from query in hibernate?

```
 Query q = session.createQuery("from com.daasl.Person");
 List<Person> l = q.list();
```

Is there a way i can get set or array directly instead of list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Query` can only return a list .

But you can convert the generic list to the generic array using the  [toArray(T[] a)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) of the java standard [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface

```
 Query q = session.createQuery("from com.daasl.Person");
 List<Person> personList = q.list();
 Person[] personArray = personList .toArray((Person[])Array.newInstance(Person.class, personList .size()));
```

To convert the list to a set , just supply the list to the constructor of the HashSet

```
  Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<Person>(personList);
```

Comment: What about if want to retrieve set?

Comment: just supply the list to the constructor of the `HashSet` , see my update please

Comment: `(Person[])Array.newInstance(Person.class, personList .size())` is the same as `new Person[personList.size()]`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a list to an array by using the following code.

```
String[] a = new String[list.size()];
list.toArray(a);
```