# casting an object array to a JPA entity array?

Tags: java, jpa

I am getting a casting exception every time I attempt to get an array of entities out of list of entities that I pull back from a jpa call.  Example...

```
QuickLaunch[] qLaunchArr = null;
List<QuickLaunch> listQL = null;
try
{
    System.out.println("testing 1..2..3");

    //qLaunchArr
    listQL = emf.createNamedQuery("getQuickLaunch").getResultList();
    Object[] objArr = listQL.toArray();
    //System.out.println(listQL.size());
    qLaunchArr = (QuickLaunch[]) listQL.toArray();       
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Bull Hockey!!!! I can't believe it's not butter!: "+e.toString());
}

[Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with [Lcom.upmc.esdm.messaging.entities.QuickLaunch;
```

That was in my server logs... (I am using WID)
and I also get this exception...

```
commonj.connector.runtime.DataHandlerException: CWLAP0507E: The response bean class for java class  method GetAllQuickLaunchComponents cannot be created. Reason java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch.
```

Comment: You get a classCastException yet don't bother quoting the actual exception and message ? Nice.

Comment: Well, I was kind of hoping that it was a common kind of thing...  But I will post the exception at your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `TypedQuery` to get the list of entities without explicit casting & prevent exceptions.

```
TypedQuery<QuickLaunch> listQL = em.createNamedQuery("QuickLaunch.getQuickLaunch", QuickLaunch.class);

List<QuickLaunch> products = listQL .getResultList();
```

Also, changed query name to identify its class or result type in more meaningful way.

Comment: No good.  I am getting another exception.  BTW.  I am trying to convert a List<QuickLaunch into a QuickLaunch Array.

Comment: @DmainEvent Is there any specific reason you are converting list to array.

Comment: That would be incorrect, I am converting from a List to an array.  It never comes out as an array.  I wish it did.  Some of the code I have up there is a result of me trying whatever I can to get an array of results out of this query.

Answer (score 1):

Alright...  I think I found the answer.  It was inspired by this post...

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060077/729820

I basically do this

```
try
    {
        System.out.println("testing 1..2..3");
        listQL = emf.createNamedQuery("getQuickLaunch").getResultList();
        System.out.println("What is the size of this list: number "+listQL.size());
        qLaunchArr = listQL.toArray(new QuickLaunch[listQL.size()]);         
    }
```

All exceptions seem to clear right up.
Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to do with JPA but Java, as it will not cast Object[] to QuickLaunch[].  Can you not use the Object array instead of a QuickLaunch[] array?